# Creating symbology based on range of values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, cartography, mapping

I would like to create a map in QGIS 3.16.13 where I am able to distinguish between forest cover increase, decrease, and stable forest.

My values are between -99 and 100. How do I create a colouring scheme based on ranges such that:

< 0.95 = forest decrease
> 100 = forest increase
<= 0.95 to <= 1.05 = stable forest

P.S.: The option for rule-based symbology isn't showing up on my properties

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [Rule-based Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification)

Comment: This option is not available anymore it seems.

Comment: It looks like you are using raster data. Rule-based symbology is for vector. Please update your question with relevant details such as the data type you are using. You can reclassify your raster and then use 'Paletted/Unique values' symbology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the raster isnt huge I usually "Reclassify it by table" and then use a "Paletted/unique values" styling:

[image]